# DateTime.now() in Flutter is fetched from?

Tags: flutter

I have turn off my network connection and changed my local Date and Time but when i run the program in Flutter:Dart(Android Studio) it still fetch the actual Date and Time and not the locally changed Date and Time. from where does the function  DateTime.now() in flutter fetch the Date and Time.

Answer (score 0):

So after a little bit digging into Dart DateTime class (Flutter is written in Dart), i found out that DateTime.now() is actually call to native code in c that call to function gettimeofday (you can find more info here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/gettimeofday.html)

Yet, didn't understand how it is been implemented.